# Django pass argument to class-based view

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a page with one charfield where the user writes some text. I need to redirect the user to another page with that text as agument:

This is the code from the first view:

```
    if form.is_valid():
        link = form.cleaned_data['play']
        print(link)
        return redirect('play_that_view', link = link)
```

This is the second view:

```
class Play_that_View(View):

    template_name = 'Play/play_that.html'

    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):

        link = self.kwargs['play']
        print(link)
        print('get')

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):

        link = self.kwargs['play']
        print(link)
```

And this is in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^play_that/', views.Play_that_View.as_view(), name = 'play_that_view'),
```

The error i get is:

```
Reverse for 'play_that_view' with keyword arguments '{'link': 'rere'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['play_that/']
```

I just need to catch the text in the back so i can process it. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: As the error says, you're passing an argument to a URL that doesn't expect it. How do you want that text to be represented in the URL?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i dont want it to be represented in the URL, i just need to catch it in the back and work some magic over it.

Comment: But you *are* trying to pass it in the URL. If you don't want to do that, perhaps try storing it in the session.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you, i used  `request.session['link'] = link `and  `link = request.session.get('link')` and i got what i expected. I didn't even know about this until now. Thx!